# Is there a way to upgrade Visual Studio Community 2015 to Professional?

Tags: visual-studio, installer, visual-studio-2015

I currently have Visual Studio 2015 Community edition installed on my computer. I am planning to upgrade to Professional edition. It took a long time to download and install Community edition onto my computer and I don't want to go through that process again. Is it possible to upgrade Community edition to Professional edition without having to download or install the entire Professional edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, but it isn't as simple as entering an upgraded product key, you also need the media.

[stackoverflow: Can Visual Studio Community 2015 be easily updated to Visual Studio Professional 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414480/can-visual-studio-community-2015-be-easily-updated-to-visual-studio-professional)

> When you buy/license Visual Studio 2015 Professional or higher, you'll
>   have access to the install media, usually an ISO file or vs_setup.exe
>   web-downloader. **Mount the ISO image and run Setup and you'll be
>   prompted to upgrade** (if I remember correctly). You cannot (to my
>   knowledge) have a side-by-side install of Community and Professional
>   Edition (unlike you can with the Express editions).
>
> **Personally I would just do a full uninstall of Community first, then a
>   clean install of Professional** - when I worked on the setup experience
>   of VS2015 I logged a whole bunch of bugs that were experienced during
>   in-version SKU upgrades (e.g. upgrading Community to Enterprise, then
>   downgrading to Professional), such as project template item templates
>   disappearing, etc. It wouldn't surprise me if these still caused
>   issues - I don't think it's worth the risk.

Comment: You indeed **canno**t have multiple versions of the same version of Visual Studio installed.  You can have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed though (i.e. VS2015, VS 2013, VS 2010, ect).  The ISO for all versions of Visual Studio can be downloaded without a license.  What @duDE is talking about is the ISO which already has your license code contained on it.  *I also suggest just removing Community then installing Professional.*